# Action Button calls multiple methods, how can i insert a short pause between them?

Tags: ios, ibaction

I have an iOS Xcode question I'm hoping someone can help me out with.  I have a simple action button that invokes a series of methods to run, however these methods all write to a stream and retrieve the input that comes in return, so I'm having a hard time reading the stream and extracting the information.

I think this is because its all happening too fast.  I would like it where i press the button and method one runs, waits half a second (for example), then method two, then method three, etc... can someone show me a simple code to do so please?

Thanks in advance, example below:

Chuck

```
- (IBAction)updateStatsButton:(id)sender {
[self method1];
[self method2];
[self method3];

self.label1.text = result from method 1;
self.label2.text = result from method 2;
self.label3.text = result from method 3;
}
```

Comment: The answers below are fairly literal answers to your question.  The question you should be asking is really how can I insure that the methods are fully executed synchronously, particularly since the individual tasks require writing and reading a response, which may have indefinite delays associated with them.  The approach you're probably looking for is to execute updateStatsButton asynchronously (using NSOperation or thread or gcd or...) while making sure that each methodN is synchronous and doesn't return until the response has been read.

Comment: Totally agree with you david, thats the approach i tried to get into now by basically putting it in a while loop to check and wait until the string for message 1 is loaded before the method for method 2 even takes off.  This way its not a timed thing, it will run itself until it gets the info it needs before moving on.  Thanks for the fast response, wasn't the answer I asked but did point me in the right direction to doing it the right way anyways.  Thanks much!

Comment: I think you're still on a side track with the looping.  Most asynchronous system services have a callback mechanism that notifies you when it completes.  By looping you're still using significant battery and probably locking up the user interface, both to,be avoided where possible.  Find a good network tutorial and that should give you some better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self method1];
});

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self method2];
});
```

Comment: You don’t need to create a block self here. You aren’t mutating the pointer, and you aren’t creating a cycle because the block isn’t retained by `self`, and it eventually releases its reference to `self`.

Comment: Appreciate the fast response and will give this a check as the right answer because it definitely answered the question I asked, its just my logic and question that were wrong!! lol  Thanks Yar :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(method1) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```